# Raven/Sentry not working when DEBUG = False in Django settings.py

Tags: python, django, sentry, raven

I have installed Sentry(6.3.2)/Raven(3.5.1) to monitor my Django 1.5.5 application, which works if I have my application on DEBUG=True in my settings.py. However, if I set it to False, no more error messages arrive at Sentry. My Raven application definitely works when tested with "python manage.py raven test"(in addition to the error messages that arrive when running Django in Debug-mode).
Sentry runs in a different virtualenvironment from my Django application and they both run through an Nginx reverse-proxy. I am running python 2.6.

My settings.py looks like this:

```
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'my_db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'my_db_user',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'my_db_pw',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com" 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "my_mail@my_provider.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "my_password"
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my_domain', 'localhost']

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Zurich'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de-ch'

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True

FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = 'my_app.formats'

MEDIA_ROOT = ''

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/path/to/static'

STATIC_URL = 'http://myip/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

SECRET_KEY = 'my_secret_key'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                               "django.core.context_processors.debug",
                               "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
                               "django.core.context_processors.media",
                               "django.core.context_processors.static",
                               "django.core.context_processors.request",
                               "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages")

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.cookie.CookieStorage'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_app.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my_app.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/paht/to/templates',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django_extensions',
    'south',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat',
)

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'root': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'handlers': ['sentry'],
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'raven': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'sentry.errors': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}

RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'dsn': 'http://some_code@www.my_domain.com/sentry/2',
}
```

and my sentry.conf.py like this:

```
from sentry.conf.server import *
import os.path

CONF_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'my_sentry_db',
        'USER': 'my_sentry_db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_sentry_db_pw',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',

    }
}

SENTRY_URL_PREFIX = '/sentry'
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/sentry'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.my_domain.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1:9002']

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SENTRY_WEB_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
SENTRY_WEB_PORT = 9002
SENTRY_WEB_OPTIONS = {
    'workers': 3,  # the number of gunicorn workers
    'secure_scheme_headers': {'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https'},
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False

SERVER_EMAIL = 'root@sentry'

SECRET_KEY = 'my_secret_key'

TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = ''
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = ''

FACEBOOK_APP_ID = ''
FACEBOOK_API_SECRET = ''

GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = ''
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = ''

GITHUB_APP_ID = ''
GITHUB_API_SECRET = ''

TRELLO_API_KEY = ''
TRELLO_API_SECRET = ''

BITBUCKET_CONSUMER_KEY = ''
BITBUCKET_CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
```

How can I get Raven/Sentry to run when not in Debug mode with Django?

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

**Update:** 
I just wanted to add, that I do receive the *"SuspiciousOperation: Invalid HTTP*_ *HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED*_ *HOSTS)*" error message on Sentry, even when the debug-mode is off.

The majority of these messages comes from the fact that I have removed one of my former domains from my ALLOWED_HOSTS list and bots are still looking for it.

And just to clarify: The messages I am not receiving in non-debug-mode are the ones where I put an "assert False" into my code or just type in some random string to throw me an error.

Comment: I've had this very problem. Try taking `www.` off the `www.my_domain.com` element in your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` entry OR perhaps add `*` for a moment to eliminate `ALLOWED_HOSTS` as a contributor to this problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip and sorry it took me so long to answer: So I tried replacing the ALLOWED_HOSTS addresses in both my settings.py file as well as my sentry.conf.py file by '*' and also '0.0.0.0'(which is the same, isn't it?), but it didn't change the behavior. I guess the good thing about it is now, that it is likely that the problem is not connected to the new ALLOWED_HOSTS security measure in Django 1.5. How did you solve the this in your case? Thanks so much for your help again!

Comment: For me it was as simple as naked domains. I was almost sure that was going to bit it for you, alas. Hrmm. So something is getting in the way of the Sentry middleware in non-debug mode - what is happening when exceptions are generated in the code, you getting 501's?

Comment: Well actually it's a 500 message that gets displayed when I do it with the debug-mode off (_Server Error (500)_ is what it says, so it's a standard Django template). Do you have any idea what else it could be that is causing this Raven/Sentry Problem?

Comment: Sorry, 501 was a typo, 500 is what I meant and is correct. Cool, well that seems fine if you are getting standard 500s out of Django. I'm thoroughly confused - out of ideas for the moment I'm sorry. If I come up with anything else, I'll post it otherwise please follow up if you figure it out. At this point I would be adding debug statements into Django / Raven code to figure out why those are not getting caught by Raven's middleware. See if you can force it with  [custom middleware](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/django.html#error-handling-middleware), isolates one more aspect.